# HTML Upload Problem, Can someone tell me about requirements?

Tags: upload, lamp

Literally, I am unable to upload anything to my server via the normal HTML file input type. Ok, Here's my setup.

-Ubuntu 9.10

-LAMP configuration

-File upload limit set to 50 mb in the php.ini file

-All the files that I try to upload are less than a meg a piece.

-I am using the standard HTML `<input type='file' name='userfile' size='20' />`, and the form has the correct EncType setting.

What I'm asking about is if there is setting somewhere that I'm missing that is throwing errors, or some such thing. I've checked permissions as well. www-data is in complete control, and there doesn't seem to be a problem at all, along those lines.

Thanks in advance.

[EDIT]  Fixee link: http://www.fixee.org/paste/p3jfr1b/

Comment: Describe your problem in more detail. Are you getting any errors (check the log files if you don't see them in your browser)

Comment: What exactly is your problem, and how do you know that it doesn't work? Could you post some code for the server-side php script so we can get an idea how you are trying it?

Comment: No, I'm not getting any PHP errors. however, I am using CodeIgniter, and I'm getting a mysterious "You did not select a file to upload" error. Which could mean anything. I've looked it up and still no dice. I've tried a number of fixes for it, but I simply can't get it to work. That's why I'm feeling like it's a settings problem or something

Comment: Have you tried writing a quick PHP page that doesn't use CodeIgniter for file uploads?  It could isolate if the framework isn't configured (there is a single PHP setting in php.ini that turns file uploading on a off, I know it's obvious but some times that is the last place we look)

Comment: I've added a fixee link (like pastebin) for you in the main question.

Comment: Post your HTML and PHP, I'm afraid we can't help without that ...

Comment: I though PHP used a special array ($_FILES) for file uploads, and not the $_POST object.

Comment: it can do both, $_FILES and $_POST

Comment: I've tried the $_FILES one, no dice.

Comment: File Uploads = ON ON, from the phpinfo().

Comment: You can't access uploaded files trough $_POST!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`do_upload()` method accepts the name of the field not the value of the field as it's argument.
Just use `->do_upload ( 'userfile' )` and it should work.

Also the `INPUT` field does not have a enctype attribute, the form does.

See [this](http://codeigniter.com/user_guide/libraries/file_uploading.html) for more info on uploading files with CodeIgniter.

Comment: hmm, give me a sec. I like where this answer is going.

Comment: no problem ;) just read the documentation next time and save yourself to trouble of asking a question :)

Answer (score 0):

Looking at the line: `if (!$this->upload->do_upload($_POST["userfile1"])) {`

I suppose you should use `$_FILES['userfile1']` instead of `$_POST['userfile1']`?